# Vue template syntax increment in mustache

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Just started learn Vue.js and I am very curious what happened in my simple code, I cannot find explenation. 
I am trying to increment counter inside mustache, but there is something weird happening with this variable

my code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 5,
    state: false
  },
  methods: {
    fun: function() {
      this.state = !this.state
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ counter }}</p>
 <button v-on:click="fun">Button</button>
 <p v-if="state">
    Miss me? {{ counter++ }}
 </p>
</div>
```

I am receiving in console `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.` when `counter++` is calling.
I think that I can run expression inside mustache sytaxt but in that case it does not work for me.

Could someone explain what is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `counter++`, which is `counter = counter + 1`, on every render call. Changing your instance state will re-render the component, which will increment the counter again and again, leading to an infinite loop like Vue correctly warns you.

Instead you should update the `counter` in your click handler function:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 5,
    state: false
  },
  methods: {
    fun: function() {
      this.counter++;
      this.state = !this.state
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ counter }}</p>
 <button v-on:click="fun">Button</button>
 <p v-if="state">
    Miss me? {{ counter }}
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, every call of `{{ counter++ }}` change state, cause rerendering, again call `{{ counter++ }}` and so on? What Vue is doing? Is it stopping that inifinte loop?

Comment: @mdolata Yes, that's what happens. And apparently Vue stops the loop after 100 iterations and outputs a warning on the console.